# How to create a multicast RTP stream in Windows (with SDP)

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, webrtc, rtp

I want to create a multicast RTP stream using ideally Windows. Linux is also acceptable.

I also want to output the SDP for this stream (so that the receiver can use it).

The stream source can be a fake signal or a video file. Either is fine.

*Note that I do not want to read a stream, rather I want to produce one!*

Please recommend a simple tool or library for this use case.

I went through the ffmpeg docs but did not see this exact use case covered.

Answer (score 1):

RTP/RTSP Streaming

live555 : http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/

Multicast & unicast streaming.

https://github.com/alm4096/FFMPEG-Live555-H264-H265-Streamer